# Can I run more than one javascript onload?

Tags: javascript

I have a page that uses modernizr.js which runs when the page loads up.  Before I added this I had a simple js clock script running to display the time which also loaded when the page loaded, however, since adding both of them to the page at the same time makes one or the other stop working.

I am still fairly new to javascript and am getting to grips with the rules (self taught).  Is it possible to ave two scripts running on load and if so how?  Or, am I barking up the wrong tree and if so is there something wrong with my code?

This is what I had...

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   if(window.FileReader && Modernizr.draganddrop){
      window.location = "http://www.dentaldigs.co.uk/image_upload.php"

   }
};
</script>

<script>
      // add a zero in front of numbers<10
      function checkTime(i)
      {
      if (i<10)
        {
          i="0" + i;
        }
      return i;
      }

      function clock()
      {
      var today=new Date();
      var h=today.getHours();
      var m=today.getMinutes();
      var s=today.getSeconds();
      m=checkTime(m);
      s=checkTime(s);
      document.getElementById('clock_div').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
      t=setTimeout(function(){clock()},500);
      }  

</script>

<body onLoad="clock()">
</body>
```

With the clock script in place the modernizr.js doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply add `clock();` to `window.onload` right after calling the Modernizr script:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   // loading modernizr
   if(window.FileReader && Modernizr.draganddrop){
      window.location = "http://www.dentaldigs.co.uk/image_upload.php"
   }
   // calling your clock script
   clock();
};
</script>
<body>
   ...
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thats what I was looking for but wasn't quite sure how to implement it.  Only problem is that if I try to add the checkTime() function it doesn't work, I have no idea why?

Comment: No idea, it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/AGwLE/ but you don't need an extra function for this. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/GYSN8/ it works like `m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning directly to `window.onload`, you should bind events using `addEventListener`.  That way you can assign multiple functions.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    console.log('first onload');
});

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    console.log('second onload');
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jjqCX/

**UPDATE**: If you are using IE < 9, you need to use `attachEvent`.

```
function loaded = function(){
    console.log('first onload');
}

function loaded2 = function(){
    console.log('second onload');
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false); 
    window.addEventListener('load', loaded2, false); 
}
else if (window.attachEvent)  {
    window.attachEvent('onload', loaded);
    window.attachEvent('onload', loaded2);
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jjqCX/1/

Answer (score 1):

use this one

```
function myFunctions() {
  function1();
  function2();
}
window.onload = myFunctions;
```